# How to calculate Peak enrollment in PeopleSoft campus solutions

Tags: peoplesoft

is there a way to figure out the number of students enrolled when xyz% of the class session has been completed in Peoplesoft Campus Solutions?

Where this value is stored and if not stored in any table directly then which fields are used to calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

The enrollment table PS_STDNT_ENRL is the starting point, so you need to get all students with an enrollment status (#1).

But that will give the number of enrollments, and you mention some % of class session completed.

This is trickier and subject to interpretation.

One way is to calculate total number of seats on the session, using CLASS_TBL (#2)

If you do `#1/#2` you know the % of seats taken.

Then you can just count the distinct EMPLIDs from (#1).